# Having some confusing issues with parsing my own site

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I am parsing one of my own websites which has a lot of static HTML content within the parse, this is causing some conflict for some reason.

The content I'm scraping isn't returning every element properly..

**Array from Parse output.**

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://example.com/7477/starlito-funerals-court-dates-2-20172
    [image] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cover-26.jpg
    [title] => Starlito – Funerals & Court Dates 2 (2017) 
    [genre] => Rap 
    [download] => http://example.org/rnh78zfq6jdl
    [tracklist] => <li class="track" data-index="0" data-file="http://example.com.pk/mp3embed-fl759o9soiuc.mp3"><a href="#" class="title name"><span class="name">01. Funerals & Court Dates 2 </span></a><ul class="actions"><li><a href="http://example.com/fl759o9soiuc" target="_blank"> <span class="fa fa-arrow-down mobile-only-ib"></span> <span class="text desktop-only-ib">Download</span> </a> </li> </ul> </li> 
)
```

The part we're looking at here is the `[tracklist]` portion, this above shows that it's scraping perfectly fine. However when I go to store it into my WordPress site it returns something like this for the `[tracklist]` portion.

```
<li class="track">
<a href="#" class="title name">
    <span class="name">01. Funerals &amp; Court Dates 2 </span>
</a>
<ul class="actions">
<li>
<a href="http://example.pk/fl759o9soiuc" target="_blank"> 
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-down mobile-only-ib"></span> 
    <span class="text desktop-only-ib">Download</span>
</a> 
</li> 
</ul>
```

For those who don't wanna look over this, it appears that it removes the `data-index="0" data-file="http://example.com.pk/mp3embed-fl759o9soiuc.mp3"` portion completely, what in the world could be the cause of this?

Another important note is that..

I think it only does this when it's ran through a **cronjob** as when I manually load the parse file, it returns everything perfectly as it appears in the array.

Comment: Are yo have two different codes there:- `one in cronjob` and something else in `manual coding`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh No sir, everything is the same. This is what's confusing me.

Comment: How are you inserting this into your wordpress site?